# Two of my devices can't connect to Wifi but everything else works

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint, galaxy-s3

I am using the Xfinity router that came with the Comcast package. My tablet, (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3) would see the router, allow me to enter the password (not saying that here), but would keep asking for the password over and over again and would never connect. My phone (Samsung Galaxy S4) connects, my laptop when it had Windows 8/8.1 on it worked fine. My XBOX 360 worked fine.

Then I replaced Windows 8/8.1 with Linux Mint, (I didn't want to post on the Unix Stack Site because I figured this was irrelevant to Linux), and it does the same thing my tablet was doing.

How do I fix the issue that both my tablet and laptop are having? What settings should I apply, if any?

Comment: Verify these devices supports the 802.11 mode your using

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do what verify if a device is using 802.11/g or 802.11n or 802.11ac its just something you know.  Confirm what modes it supports by looking at the product specification the confirm what mode your router is set to use.

Comment: I'm not even sure i know

Comment: Have you checked that you set the security mode correctly? (i.e. TKIP/AES cipher, open system / shared key)

Comment: I didn't change the settings at all

Comment: The device s that work are WPA/WPA 2/FT PSK but the Linux Mint is WPA & WPA 2 Personal